# Error 41 with brunch

Tags: android, android-source, cyanogenmod

Good afternoon,

I've previously been able to build CM 10.1 onto my P5110 (Galaxy Tab 2). Since then, I've tried to import the project to Eclipse. I suspect that it may have done something that causes the following errors.

```
packages/apps/SoundRecorder/gen/com/android/soundrecorder/R.java:6: duplicate class: com.android.soundrecorder.R
public final class R {
             ^
target thumb C++: libwilhelm <= frameworks/wilhelm/src/android/AudioPlayer_to_android.cpp
target thumb C++: libwilhelm <= frameworks/wilhelm/src/android/AudioRecorder_to_android.cpp
packages/apps/CMWallpapers/gen/com/cyanogenmod/CMWallpapers/R.java:6: duplicate class: com.cyanogenmod.CMWallpapers.R
public final class R {
             ^
target thumb C++: libwilhelm <= frameworks/wilhelm/src/android/MediaPlayer_to_android.cpp
target thumb C++: libwilhelm <= frameworks/wilhelm/src/android/OutputMix_to_android.cpp
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error
make: *** [/home/can/android/system/out/target/common/obj/APPS/SoundRecorder_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar] Error 41
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Note: packages/apps/CMWallpapers/src/com/cyanogenmod/CMWallpapers/wallpaper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error
make: *** [/home/can/android/system/out/target/common/obj/APPS/CMWallpapers_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar] Error 41
packages/apps/CMFileManager/gen/com/cyanogenmod/filemanager/R.java:6: duplicate class: com.cyanogenmod.filemanager.R
public final class R {
             ^
1 error
make: *** [/home/can/android/system/out/target/common/obj/APPS/CMFileManager_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar] Error 41
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have added the project to eclipse, this would have added `gen` and `bin` folders in `SoundRecorder`.

So delete these folders before you give android platform build

Comment: I've since deleted and re-inited the repo. I can't confirm this works but it sounds likely to be the solution. If someone can confirm this to work, I'll accept the answer.